# Find $B(B^{T}B)^{-1}B^{T}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> To find:
>   $$B(B^{T}B)^{-1}B^{T}$$
>   for $B=[0,1,-1]^T$
>   I have
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}
> 0\\ 
> 1\\ 
> -1
> \end{bmatrix} \left ([0,1,-1]\begin{bmatrix}
> 0\\ 
> 1\\ 
> -1
> \end{bmatrix}  \right )^{-1}[0,1,-1]$$
>   but where to from here?

Comment: Carry out the indicated operations.  Inside the round parentheses, you have two matrices to multiply.  They will give you a number, which you should invert as indicated by the $-1$ power.  Then two more multiplies and you ar done.  The $B$s you plugged in are not correct.  $B=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
-1
\end{bmatrix}$  But there is a simpler way if you don't plug in the value of $B$

Comment: $B^T=([0,1,-1]^T)^T=[0,1,-1]$. How did it transform to $[1,-1,0]$?

Comment: If you’re trying to work through the last method of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1867286/265466), then you’re using the wrong vector(s). The above will give you the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto the span of $[0,1,-1]^T$, but in that problem you need its orthogonal complement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply notice that 
$$[0,1,-1]\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
-1
\end{bmatrix} = 0\cdot0 + 1\cdot1 + (-1)\cdot(-1)=2.$$
So in the end you get $\frac12BB^T$. (Which should be easy to calculate. You should get a $3\times3$ matrix.)